# Handling error: NestedServletException, Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I took these codes from github and they work good a lone but when put them in my project i have errors
I'm trying to implement oauth2 in spring boot but i have these two errors

```
INFO 28433 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: NestedServletException, Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
WARN 28433 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

this is my oauth2 configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/greeting").authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            endpoints.allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);

            endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore).authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            clients.inMemory().withClient("clientapp")
                    // .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    // .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials", "password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("123456")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30 * 24 * 3600);

        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }

    }

}
```

and CustomUserDetails class

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final CustomerRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(CustomerRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Customers user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        }
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends Customers implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(Customers user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return getRoles();
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return getUsername();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

I have tried to make a lot of changes but nothing work,it always give me the same error,So what is the reason here?

Comment: Add some more logs with level `DEBUG` enabled for spring Security.

Comment: @dur how can i enable this?

Comment: You have to change your log configuration.